# Glassfish basic configuration forgotten

Tags: glassfish, java

I installed glassfish v3 some time ago and it's been a while since I last used it, so I forgot the port on which the server is listening and the port on which the admin console is listening. Moreover, i forgot the admin password!

I'm pretty sure I've change them because I've tried the default values and didn't work.

Is there any configuration file where I can look for them (at least the port numbers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port for admin console is normally 4848.

Check the domain.xml file under the config dir in your Glassfish Domain.

```
${glassfish_domain_dir}/config/domain.xml
```

And for overriding password, refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-6823/abgdh/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
 netstat -l
```

will give you all the listening ports, so you can start from there.